# In-App Purchase return 0 product

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store, in-app-purchase

The `productsRequest:didReceiveResponse:` returns 0 in `[response.products count]`. I've checked [again](https://devforums.apple.com/thread/23344?start=0&tstart=0) and [again](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/21035-problems-creating-test-user-app-purchase.html) and the only thing I am not sure is the about the status:

[image]

Are **Waiting for Review** items not returned in `productsRequest:didReceiveResponse:`?

Comment: Did you set up your profile correctly? Your dev profile cannot have any '*' in it, so if your app's bundle id is 'org.example.app', the profile you sign with must also be set for 'org.example.app'. This is the most common reason for getting no valid ids during development.

Comment: Yes, my profiles are newly created without `*`, it is a `com.company.appname` and the purchase item is `com.company.appname.proversion`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by re-create a new profile.